# Javascript Error: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

Tags: javascript

`CM_Contract__c` is a custom object and `Opportunity__c` is a lookup field. I am getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

Here's my code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/23.0/connection.js")} 
var result = sforce.connection.query("select Name from CM_Contract__c where Opportunity__r.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: it seems to be correct. can you post your rest of the code ?

Comment: I don't mind but there is lot of custom settings and objects used is it okay?

Comment: are you sure error on this line ? It seems error is coming at some other place when javascript trying to access value of name attribute

Comment: Agree with @Himanshu, try doing a console.log(result) after your query and you'll probably see that you're not getting any result returned.

Comment: @Himanshu I'm very confident that error is in those few lines of code only as I've checked my code without those lines of code and it is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your javascript code?

Comment: I'm sorry now that plan is chalked out of scope and I'm trying something new. Anyways I thank all of you for your precious time and suggestions.